# If $T_n(x)$ is the Taylor Polynomial of order n for $f$, centered at $a$, find the Taylor Polynomial of $g(x)=f(b-x)$ centered at $b-a$

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

If $T_n(x)$ is the Taylor Polynomial of order n for $f$, centered at $a$, find the Taylor Polynomial of $g(x)=f(b-x)$ centered at $b-a$. Explain the answer.

$$T_n(x)=\sum_{k=0}^n  \frac{f^k(a)}{k!}(x-a)^k $$

If $S_n(x)$ is the polynomial of order n of $g(x)$, centered at $b-a$:

\begin{align}
S_n(x)&=\sum_{k=0}^n  \frac{g^k(b-a)}{k!}(x-(b-a))^k\\
&= \sum_{k=0}^n  \frac{f^k(b-(b-a))}{k!}(b-x-(b-a))^k\\
&= \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{f^k(a)}{k!}(-x+a)^k
\end{align}

Am I mistaken somewhere? And where can I go from here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have some algebra mistakes. It should be
\begin{align}
S_n(x) &= \sum_{k=0}^n\dfrac{g^{(k)}(b-a)}{k!}[x-(b-a)]^k \\
&= \sum_{k=0}^n \dfrac{(-1)^k f^{(k)}(b-(b-a))}{k!}[x-(b-a)]^k \\
&= \sum_{k=0}^n \dfrac{f^{(k)}(a)}{k!}[(b-a)-x]^k \\
&= \sum_{k=0}^n \dfrac{f^{(k)}(a)}{k!}[(b-x) - a]^k
\end{align}
How can you write this in terms of $T_n(\cdot)$?